# Meteorjs Reactivity from one template A to another template B

Tags: javascript, meteor

If there is template A has a `counterA` variable which will increment the `counterA` value on click. And there is another template B and has `counterB` which will increment its value on `counterA` reactivity. How to archive this scenario without using session variables?

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply declare your variables globally

Comment: Thnaks @Anis Could you please give me an example how to achieve this?

Comment: Declare your reactiveVar without var: counterA = new ReactiveVar(); then from your template B you can access to its value with counterA.get()